# How to hide a customization link themes menu in wordpress?

Tags: links

Anyone know how to hide or remove customization menu in wordpress?

The link menu seen in

OPTIONS:Widgets Menus ***Theme Options***

and

Appearance

-Theme

-Widgets

-Menus

***-Theme Option***

-Editor

Thank you

Comment: your theme enables this,

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a default wordpress menu, your theme adds that using [`add_theme_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) function.

Just remove *( or comment out `//`, so in future you can enable it again )* that from `functions.php` file to remove the menu completely.

> #### Update -
>
> There's another ***(More Efficient)*** way is using Wordpress Function - [remove menu page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)
>
> <sup>- **@Wyck**</sup>

Comment: It's better to use `remove_menu_page` for a user role, that enables admins to use it, but hides it from other users.

Comment: Yup. that'll be even better.